# How to activate time left notification in Google Family Link?

Tags: notifications, parental-control, google-family-link

I installed the Google Family Link app on my kid's phone, mainly to limit his screen time.

He asked me to be notified before his time is running out but I can't find a way to activate such a notification.
Is there a way my son can tell how much time he has left to use his phone?

Comment: Possibly related:  ["Showing how much per-app screen time allowance is remaining, on a child device running Google Family Link"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249059/showing-how-much-per-app-screen-time-allowance-is-remaining-on-a-child-device-r).